# What is a sysroot exactly and how do I create one ?

Tags: linux

I'm working with QT and embedded devices and in many documentation items ( [like here](http://doc.qt.io/QtQuick2DRenderer/qtquick2drenderer-installation-guide.html)) they are talking about sysroots. I've searched the web but I couldn't find anything about what a sysroot is. I have a cross-compiler-toolchain though. What's a sysroot and how do I create one ?

Comment: To answer the second part of the question... something like http://crosstool-ng.github.io may help to create the sysroot

Answer (score 109, accepted):

A sysroot is a directory which is considered to be the root directory for the purpose of locating headers and libraries.  So for example if your build toolchain wants to find `/usr/include/foo.h` but you are cross-compiling and the appropriate `foo.h` is in `/my/other/place/usr/include/foo.h`, you would use `/my/other/place` as your sysroot.

Comment: I would find this answer more useful if it clarified the differences between sysroot and a staging directory.